# Error in WCF while hosting to the server

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, web-config

I have created a wcf Service this service is giving an error after deploy on the server
this Service is working fine at Local host so i don't know where i am wrong

[image]

and my **Service.svc** is:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="mobile.Service" CodeBehind="Service.svc.cs" %>
```

my **web.config**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <!--Path for Photo Gallery Images-->
    <add key="PhotoGalleryPath" value="http://www.abc.com/photogallery/"/>
    <!--Path for Video Gallery Images-->
    <add key="VideoPath" value="http://www.abc.com/video/"/>
    <!--Path for Video URL-->
    <add key="VideoURLPath" value="http://ventunotech.com/watch/"/>
    <!--Path for Web URL for Share News through mail, FB, Twitter-->
    <add key="WebUrlforNews" value="http://www.abc.com/news.aspx?id="/>
    <add key="WebUrlforArticle" value="http://www.abc.com/article.aspx?id="/>
    <!--Folder Name with Path for News and Article Images (Change this according to Your Server Folder Path) and give this folder to write permission-->
    <add key="ImagePath" value="http://www.abc.com/mobile/images/"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="con" connectionString="Data Source=184.122.1.55;Initial Catalog=Data;Integrated Security=SSPI;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="APIService.ServiceBehavior" name="APIService.Service">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="APIService.IService"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="APIService.ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="web" maxBufferPoolSize="1500000" maxReceivedMessageSize="1500000" maxBufferSize="1500000">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="656000" maxBytesPerRead="656000" maxDepth="32" maxNameTableCharCount="656000" maxStringContentLength="656000"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

my **IService.cs**

```
namespace APIService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/GetCities", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
                    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        ItemList GetCities();

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/GetStates", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
                    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        ItemList GetStates();  

 }
    [DataContract]
    public class Item
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class ItemList
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

}

my **Service.svc.cs**

```
namespace APIService
{
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Service : IService
    {
        SqlConnection offcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ToString());
        SqlDataAdapter adp;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        ItemList items = new ItemList();
        NewsList newslist = new NewsList();
        CommentList commentslist = new CommentList();
        UserProfile userPrf = new UserProfile();

        #region CityList
        public ItemList GetCities()
        {
            try
            {
                adp = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from tblCity", offcon);
                adp.Fill(ds, "City");

                DataTable City = ds.Tables["City"];
                var item = (from d in City.AsEnumerable()
                            select new Item
                            {
                                ID = d.Field<Int32>("intCityId").ToString(),
                                Name = d.Field<string>("strTitle")
                            }).ToList();

                items.Items = item;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Message.ToString();
            }
            return new ItemList { Items = items.Items };
        }
        #endregion

        #region StateList
        public ItemList GetStates()
        {
            try
            {
                adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblState ", offcon);
                adp.Fill(ds, "State");

                DataTable State = ds.Tables["State"];
                var item = (from d in State.AsEnumerable()
                            select new Item
                            {
                                ID = d.Field<Int32>("intStateId").ToString(),
                                Name = d.Field<string>("strTitle")
                            }).ToList();
                items.Items = item;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Message.ToString();
            }
            return new ItemList { Items = items.Items };
        }
        #endregion
}
}
```

I don't know where I am wrong, I have tried the answer of the following links but nothing works for me:

- [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720807/wcf-service-attribute-value-in-the-servicehost-directive-could-not-be-found)
- [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283963/problem-with-type-of-service-in-servicehost-directive-in-wcf-service)

If any one can help...

Comment: Looks like you are missing a reference.  Where is the `mobile.Service` type defined ?  Is it referenced ?

Comment: i didnt get u...
mobile.service is basically the namespace and the class

Comment: Is the full name of the class (including namespace) mobile.Service or is the namespace missing?  Note also that the name is case sensitive.

Comment: can u place the code behind also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error denotes that the IIS is not able to find the type `mobile.Service`. There could be many reasons why it is not able to find the type. I suggest you to specify the assembly name also in the service attribute.

Also, you can check whether the assembly really contains the type by using `ILDasm`.

**Update**

Try

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="APIService.Service" CodeBehind="Service.svc.cs" %>
```

Comment: and how to define assembly name in the service attribute

Comment: Try `"mobile.Service, <AssemblyNameHere>"`

Comment: can you please mention in your Answer that where should i put this act i get it but a little bit confuse so if u can

Comment: I don't know your assembly name... change it like `<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="mobile.Service,AssemblyNameHere" CodeBehind="Service.svc.cs" %>`

Comment: okk and also i have updated my question with the whole code behind

Comment: no actually wht u have updated is basically my mistake i have created the solution with another name n tried but didnt work and i have pasted that code bt didnt change the image

Comment: Your code, is not showing the assembly name. You can get it from the project properties and update the Service attribute

Comment: my assembly name is APIService and i have tried wht u have said in your comment but it didnt work a really dont get that where i am wrong as this is working perfectly on local but on server i dnt know whts happening

Comment: See, if the type actually exist in the dll, using ILDasm

Comment: it is showing .assembly APIService {.ver 1:0:0:0 } is it correct
should i register this dll at server side

Comment: check if the type exists inside it... you can google to know how to do it.

Comment: i have used **Type my = Type.GetType("APIService.Service,APIService");** and its giving values like name and fullname which are Service and APIService.Service

Comment: One last thing I can think of is, to place the svc file in the root of the virtual directory instead of inside the folders.

Comment: it is already in the root:
i have this path: d:/host/mobile/Service.svc
and we.config is also at this path
and dll is in the bin folder.:d:/host/mobile/bin/APIService.dll